# Snakemake syntax for multiple outputs with the use of checkpoint

Tags: pipeline, snakemake

I'm using snakemake to build a pipeline. I have a checkpoint that should produce multiple output files. These output files are later used in my rule all within expand. The thing is that I don't know the amount of files that will be produced and therefore can't specify a dataset in expand.

The files will be produced in a R-script.

Example:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand(["results/{output}],
               output=????)



checkpoint rscript:
    input:
        "foo.input"
    output:
        report("somedir/{output}"),
    script:
        "../scripts/foo.R"
```

Of course this is only a small part but I basically have a loop in my R-script to output multiple files in the somedir. But since I don't know how many and because they are firstly evaluated in the R script I can't set output in expand.

Maybe this is a really trivial question to some of you, or even a stupid question and there are better ways to do this. If that's the case I'd still be thankful cause I had problems understanding most of the snakemake functions because of my ability to comprehend the functions in english.

If there are more questions I'd gladly answer. (The best case for me would be to let output have names that I could specify in runtime within the R script)

(I also can't aggregate the created files in another rule, because each file will show a different plot)

Edit: The main problem still seems to be that checkpoint rscript is not able to create multiple {output} files in "somedir/". The attempt with touch("rscript_finish.flag") seems to output only the svg File as "rscript_finish.flag" or seems to override "rscript_finish.flag" each time the loop in my rscript writes into snakemake@output[[1]].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no stupid questions :). I hope I understood, and it was actually not a trivial question at all!

```
def all_input(wildcards):
    checkpoints.rscript.get()  # make sure that checkpoint rscript is executed
    filenames, = glob_wildcards("somedir/{filenames}.png")  # find all the output_files of rscript
    return expand("somedir_cp/{fn}", fn=filenames)


rule all:
    input:
        all_input


rule add_to_report:
    input:
        "somedir/{filename}.png"
    output:
        report("somedir_cp/{filename}.png")
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"


checkpoint rscript:
    input:
        "foo.input"
    output:
        touch("rscript_finish.flag")
    script:
        "../scripts/foo.R"
```

I didn't really test the code, so I am not sure if it immediatly works, but I think the logic is correct.

The way this needs to be solved is with an extra rule, which I called `add_to_report`. All this rule does is make a copy of the existing output of `rscript`, and adds it to the report. The way `rule all` works is that it first calls for the execution of `checkpoint rscript`. Once that one is executed it finds all the files it generated. Then it says that `rule all` needs as input the copy of each file `rscript` generated, which will be made by `rule add_to_report`, and thus the files are added to the report.

Comment: I will go to bed soon, if it doesn't work let me know and I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: One more thing right now, if you're still online. Regarding touch(). When executing touch in combination with checkpoint is supposed to capture the output files right? Cause as of now, when performing a loop, it seems to override the output each time and only leaves me with 1 png for example instead of let's say 3 when I loop through 3 times in the R script.

Comment: I don't think I've understood what rule rscript outputs. Is it called only once? Or is it supposed to be called multiple times?

Comment: rule/checkpoint rscript is called once but outputs multiple files (for example png), but as far as I understood and tried, checkpoint works similair to dynamic therefore 1 call should be fine I guess? It produces for example "1.png","2.png","3.png" (I don't know the name before hand, the name is evaluated during the r script runtime)

Comment: Not sure how the internals work in the r script, so probably just changing it back to "somedir/{output}" should be fine. That change of mine wasn't necessary anyways

Comment: I updated my question. Maybe it's a bit easier for you to understand now, what my problem is.

Comment: You will have to change the rscript to change the output name every time.in the loop.

Comment: How can I do so? Because it´s somewhat important to be able to access the names of the created files later on, like I´d be able to do with {output}

Comment: I don't know what your r script does, maybe you can translate its logic to how many files will be generated. But in its current form its not possible. The problem is not with snakemake. The rscipt makes multiple output in a loop, but somehow the script tries to give them all the same name. That should be changed.

Comment: I sent you in a chat request the Rscript code to not extend the discussion here further, maybe it's more intuitive to understand this way. Anyways thank you a lot so far, learned quite a bit through the answer you provided/or better said it helped me to understand checkpoints with wildcards a bit better in this regard.